# svn log -- configure default number of entries

Tags: svn, configuration, logging

Is there a way to set the number of entries shown by `svn log`, i.e. a default `--limit` somewhere? Say, in a config file in user's home directory, for instance?

If not, probably a way to add a custom command, like in `git`? (The existence of [svn-command](http://svn-command.rubyforge.org/) suggests such capability is not built-in.)

Answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881129/how-do-you-see-recent-svn-log-entries) question seem to suggest it is not possible, but just to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell alias in case of proper OS (i.e - not Windows cmd), bat-files if Win

Comment: Thanks, was looking to avoid alias since it doesn't feel like an svn command. A wrapper like svn-command is closer to what I look for, but was wondering if such functionality is built-in.

Comment: @user1243838 - it **can feel like** new svn command - see [Command aliases for Subversion, Git and Rails](http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/command-aliases-for-subversion-git-and-rails/) example and yes, it doesn't exist in core - you can read really old (2002 year) topic started with [this message](http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2002-11/1611.shtml)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the 2002 thread, good to know I not the only or first one to desire such functionality ;) . Though I am not sure how the other link solves the point 1) made on that mailing list -- which is what I was referring to by **feel like**. Thanks again for your helpful replies.