# Get file list of last N commits in Subversion

Tags: shell, svn, version-control

Is it possible to get file list of last N commits in Subversion?

I'd like to run image optimization task for the files in Subversion repository, and I don't want to run through whole files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you see recent SVN log entries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881129/how-do-you-see-recent-svn-log-entries)

Comment: Not a duplicate, because that question is asking for the most recent few log entries. This question doesn't care about the log entries, only the files changed in those log entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the last N commits, use the `--limit` or `-l` flag to `svn log`. Alternatively, you can also limit your log entries by revision number and/or by date.

To get the files changed, you need to use the `-v` (or `--verbose`) flag.

And to suppress the log text, you need to use the `-q` (or `--quiet`) flag.

Putting it all together, to get (for example) all files changed since the beginning of May 2014 (in easy to parse format), you could do this:

```
svn log --quiet --verbose --revision {2014-05-01}:HEAD
svn log -q -v -r {2014-05-01}:HEAD
```

or to get the same info for the last 10 commits, no matter when they happened:

```
svn log --quiet --verbose --limit 10
svn log -q -v -l 10
```

Comment: "I don't know of a way to get the last N commits" - OMFG!!! RTFM `svn help log` `-l` option

Comment: Right you are! How embarrassing. You can tell how often I drop to the command-line in SVN. I'm editing the post with that info!

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple, single Subversion command that will give you that information.

There are a few *loose ends* here:

- Do you mean the last few revisions of the directory (project) you're in, or of the entire repository. If you're talking about the entire repo, you could get the latest revision, and then subtract out the number you want. If you're talking about the individual project, it gets a lot tougher.
- I take it you want a list that doesn't contain duplicates.
- What about files that were added or deleted? How do you want to count those?

This isn't as difficult as it seems, but you'll have to write your own script to do this. The `svn log` takes a `--xml` parameter and will return the log in XML format. The format looks like this:

```
$ svn log -v --xml $REPO

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
<logentry
    revision=...>
<author>...</author>
<date>...</date>
<paths>
<path
   ....
   ....
   action=".">...name of file...</path>
<path ...
</paths>
<msg>.....</msg>
</logentry>
<logentry
   ....
   ....
```

Even if you don't parse the XML itself, you could easily use the XML output to get the information you need. Count the number of `<logentry` lines until you get the number or entries you want. Use the `<path` to mark the beginning of the`element, and when you see the closing`>`, you know that the rest of the line till the`` is the name of the file. Store these files in a hash variable keyed by the name of the file.

A script in Python or Perl should be pretty easy to do.

Comment: I didn't know about `--xml` parameter, but with Ben's and your answer I found a way to solve my problem. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question "shell" so chances are you are not on Windows, but on the off-chance you are, one can do almost anything in one line of PowerShell (substitute your value of "n" for the "99" in this recipe):

```
PS> Get-SvnLog |
Select -First 99 -ExpandProperty Paths |
% { ([xml]$_).SelectNodes("//path/text()").Value } |
Sort -Unique
```

You can see the API for Get-SvnLog in my [open source bookshelf](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/APIbookshelf.html), which includes more than 20 other examples of reports you can get. Open the PowerShell "book" and go to SvnTools. Download the code [here](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/download.html).