# Useful SVN commands

Tags: svn

I understand that the word 'useful' could be interpreted as opinionated, so I'll phrase this another way.

In GIT after using it for a year, i stumbled across

`git log --decorate --graph --stat`

Which produces a *much* more useful output than the default `git log`. However I only found this from a recommended video talk on GIT.

I have recently started learning SVN, the closest thing [I have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881129/how-do-you-see-recent-svn-log-entries) is

`svn log -l 4`

I don't think this is particularly helpful. Is there an SVN command with various parameters (or linux commands) that would give a more helpful output? - `svn info` and `svn status` aside.

Comment: You should *define* helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Subversion command-line client commands accept [`--verbose` option](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.verbose) which produces more detailed output.

Regarding `svn log` command, use [`--search` and `--search-and` options](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search). Using them you can search revision history by author, date, log message text and changed path. Moreover, it supports glob-syntax wildcards.